# Raspberry Pi Sense Hat with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyinstaller

I am quite new to developing and experimenting on Raspberry Pi, but here is my issue. I want to use pyinstaller to build my application on raspberry pi, but there is a few issues with this. Most Sense Hat modules works fine when running them from a python executable, but if I call show_message() to display on the led matrix, no matter what I want it do display, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "app.py", line 17, in <module>   
File "app.py", line 13, in func   
File "sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 481, in show_message   
File "sense_hat/sense_hat.py", line 454, in _get_char_pixels 
KeyError: '?' 
[30072] Failed to execute script 'app' due to unhandled exception!
```

The project have installed all the necessary dependencies such as sense-hat and RTIMULib. Keep in mind that this error, only happens when running the executable, and so far only for show_message(), this is not a problem running the code directly with the ./venv/bin/activate as source. I think this is an issue with pyinstaller, so if someone have encountered an error like this before, and found a solution, I will be grateful!

Comment: This question may yield more help over at [Raspberry PI](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange where folks can speak to both the programming and the physical set up to help troubleshoot further.